# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/...................... on line 45

Tags: php

I have been trying to figure out this error for a long time and I still can't figure it out I have gone throught the code several time and I still cant see the issue myself. can anyone else tell me what the issue is please? I just keep getting the same

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/........... on line 45

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "********";
$dbpass = "*********";
$dbbase = "*************";
$cron_are_so_cool = "f722g853pqx91k470343t3i3s9v5kz12";
$db = "mysql_tut";
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbbase);
function in_event($player, $text)
{
 $player = abs(intval($player));
 $text = stripslashes($text);
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `member_events` 
              VALUES('NULL', 
                     '".mysql_real_escape_string($player)."', 
                     '".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."',
                     unix_timestamp(), 
                     '0')") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("UPDATE `city_statistic` 
              SET `cs_value` = `cs_value` + '1'
              WHERE `cs_id` = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
 function id_sroom($id)
{
   $storage = array(0=>0,1=>4,2=>8,3=>18,4=>30);
   return $storage[$id];
}
/*----------------------------------5 minutes--------------------------*/
mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `my_nerve`=`my_nerve` + '1' WHERE `my_nerve` <`my_maxnerve`");
mysql_query("UPDATE `members_dogs` 
             SET `md_hunger` = `md_hunger` + '".rand(1,2)."'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `members_dogs` 
             SET `md_hunger` = '100'
             WHERE `md_hunger` > '100'");
```

The error I keep getting is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/............ on line 45

Comment: No close bracket for `in_event()`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

You have started the function definition with:

```
function in_event($player, $text)
```

but forgot to close it before declaring another function.